# Json Twitter Search - How to

Tags: python, json, twitter

I'm trying to create strings from the `u'text':` & `u'id':` found in `u'results':` So that I can compare new IDs to the last one read and display the text if it is new. I cannot currently parse(?) only the information I want.

```
import json
import urllib
from pprint import pprint
j =json.loads(urllib.urlopen('http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=%23tory&result_type=recent&rpp=1').read())
pprint(j)
```

This gives me

> 

```
{u'completed_in': 0.007,
 u'max_id': 312184292639920129L,
 u'max_id_str': u'312184292639920129',
 u'next_page': u'?page=2&max_id=312184292639920129&q=%23tory&rpp=1&result_type=recent',
 u'page': 1,
 u'query': u'%23tory',
 u'refresh_url': u'?since_id=312184292639920129&q=%23tory&result_type=recent',
 u'results': [{u'created_at': u'Thu, 14 Mar 2013 12:51:50 +0000',
               u'from_user': u'DerbysLabour',
               u'from_user_id': 393219652,
               u'from_user_id_str': u'393219652',
               u'from_user_name': u'Derbyshire Labour',
               u'geo': None,
               u'id': 312184292639920129L,
               u'id_str': u'312184292639920129',
               u'iso_language_code': u'en',
               u'metadata': {u'result_type': u'recent'},
               u'profile_image_url': u'http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1594091282/Labour_group_normal.jpg',
               u'profile_image_url_https': u'https://si0.twimg.com/profile_images/1594091282/Labour_group_normal.jpg',
               u'source': u'&lt;a href=&quot;http://twitter.com/&quot;&gt;web&lt;/a&gt;',
               u'text': u'RT @WubeyOneKenobi: Not seen a single #Tory campaigning for #DCC elections round #Glossop yet.  Scared to come out?'}],
 u'results_per_page': 1,
 u'since_id': 0,
 u'since_id_str': u'0'}
```

in return (depending on the tweet)

How do we read the Text & ID from the Results only?

Comment: JSON objects have to be loaded entirely, you can't skip over parts of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `j` variable is a `dict`, and `results` is an array containing a `dict`. You can extract the values like so:

```
text = j['results'][0]['text']
id = j['results'][0]['id']
```

If you have more results, you can do the following:

```
texts = {}
results = j['results']

for result in results:
    text = result['text']
    id = results['id']
    texts[id] = text
```

As a result you have a single `dict` called `texts` where the id is the key.

Comment: `results` is an array containing a dict.